# working with arrays php need some advice

Tags: php, arrays

need some help figuring this out, ive got some code like so

```
    $q= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");

    while($array2[] = $q->fetch_object());
    array_pop($array2);



if(isset($array2[0]->DATE))
{
    $date0 = $array2[0]->DATE;
}else{
    $date0 = '';
}
if(isset($array2[1]->DATE))
{
    $date1 = $array2[1]->DATE;
}else{
    $date1 = '';
}
$data =('DATE1'= $date0,'DATE2'= $date1)
```

so you can see what the problem is , repeating stuff over and over , its horrible, im sure theres a clean way on doing it, but im not sure how, i tried using a for loop, but if 1 value was not set all other values would get the `''` set to them so it didnt work... what i need to end up having is something that increments the `'DATE#'` equal to the occurrences inside the `$array2`

so that if `$array2` ranged from `$array[0] to $array[4]` then inside the `$data` array i would end up having `DATE0 = $date0,DATE1 = $date1,DATE2 = $date2,DATE3 = $date3,DATE4 = $date4,DATE5 = $date5` hopefully that way if for example `array2[7]` does not exists , it wont throw an error because inside `$data` it would not exist... hope all that makes sense,  i can not find a proper way to describe this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what you are doing with with the while "loop" and the array_pop, but for your other problem, you can use a simple `foreach`:

```
foreach ($array2 as $arr)
{
    $date[] = (isset($arr->DATE)) ? $arr->DATE : '';
}
```

This will get you an array with all the dates stored at the corresponding key from 0 to x.

Comment: i will accept it , not what i was looking for because noticed, i cant write what i want correctly , my sentences lost their sense, ( not native english speaker) but it lead me to some other correction i needed ty

Comment: You're welcome. If you still need help just try to edit your question or ask a new one!